# Uploading multiple files and giving the uploaded file a new name in PHP

Tags: php

Hi so I have this upload script, that can upload one file at the time but I need to upload more than one file at the same time and then name every uploaded file as `1` and the next file as `2` and the next one as `3` and so on.

```
    <?php
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png","JPG");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1032) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("i/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    }
    else
    {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "i/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo "Stored in: " . "i/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
    }
    }
    else
   {
   echo "Invalid file";
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: did anything below help?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do like this:

```
        $files = array();

        $allowed_filetypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','bmp','png','tif','pdf');
        $max_filesize = 15242880;
        $upload_path = 'images/image_uploads/';

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++){
            if($_FILES['files']['name'][$i] != "") {
                $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                $file_info = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);
                $ext = strtolower($file_info['extension']);
                //echo "<span style='font-size: 20px; color: #ff3333;'>".$ext."</span>";

                if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
                    die("The file you attempted to upload ($filename) is not allowed.");

                if(filesize($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i]) > $max_filesize)
                    die("The file you attempted to upload ($filename) is too large.");

                if(!is_writable($upload_path))
                    die("You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.");

                $filename = ($i+1).".".$ext;
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],$upload_path.$filename)) {
                    $result = mysql_query("Insert Into image_uploads_images (upload_id, image, original_name) Values ('$id', '$filename', '".$_FILES['files']['name'][$i]."');");

                    if($result){
                        array_push($files, "http://www.site.com/images/image_uploads/$filename => ".$_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);
                    }else{
                        echo "<p style=\"color:#cc3333;\">Unable to upload ".$_FILES['files']['name'][$i]."</p>";
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "<p style=\"color:#cc3333;\">Unable to upload ".$_FILES['files']['name'][$i]."</p>";
                }
            }
        }
```

**Edit**

Just as a brief explanation, all file inputs would have the same name, in this case `files`.  But when you do that, you need to add `[]` behind the name in the form element, like `<input type="file" name="files[]" />` so that it comes through as an array.

Once you have the `$_FILES` array you can go through it recursively for each file uploaded and do with it what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just use several inputs on your html:

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>
```

And in your PHP

```
<?php  

    for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['name']); $i++) { 
        $new_file = $_FILES['name'][$i] . '.' . $i+1; 
    }

?>
```

The later will create the filenames appending the index +1 so you'll have:

- myfile1.txt.1
- myfile1.txt.2

Adjust as needed.

**Edit:** [Check this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php).